# How to add native javascript into `$.when`?

Tags: jquery, getscript

How can I add native javascript into `$.when`? I get an error for doing this below when I want to use for each inside `$.when`. Any ideas?

```
var scripts = [
    "ccommon.js",
    "ccommon2.js",
    "ccommon3.js"
];

$.when(
    // Via $.getScript.
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        $.getScript(scripts[i]);
    }
).done(function(){

    //place your code here, the scripts are all loaded.
    alert('script loaded');

});
```

Comment: When you call a function, the arguments must be a list of *expressions*, i.e. `foo(expr1, expr2, ...)`. You cannot put a *statement* there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the list of promise objects as as argument list like `$.when(p1, p2, p3).then(function())` since in this case you have an dynamic list, you can use [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function invoke the [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) which the dynamic list of parameters

```
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    array.push($.getScript(scripts[i]));
}

$.when.apply($, array).done(function(){

    //place your code here, the scripts are all loaded.
    alert('script loaded');

});
```